# Retrieve the last class in an element that has mutiple classes

Tags: jquery

How can I retrieve the last class in an element that has multiple classes assigned to it using Jquery
ie.

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var cls = $('div').attr('class').split(' ');

alert(cls[cls.length-1]);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ttFSU/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regular expression version if you prefer.

```
var lastClass = $(selector).attr('class').match(/\s([^\s]+)$/)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to retrieve `class3` in this case, am I right?

```
var lastClassName = $.trim($("elementRef").attr("class")).split(" ").slice(-1);
```